# Hash a set of three indexes in a key for dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have a matrix of data with three indexes: i, j and k

I want to enter some of the data in this matrix into a dictionary, and be able to find them afterwards in the dictionary.

The data itself can not be the key for the dict.

I would like the i,j,k set of indexes to be the key.

I think I need to "hash" (some sort of hash) in one number from which I can get back the i,j,k. I need the result key to be ordered so that:

- key1 for 1,2,3 is greater than
- key2 for 2,1,3 is greater than
- key3 for 2,3,1

Do you know any algorithms to get the keys from this set of indexes? Or is there a better structure in python to do what I want to do?

I can't know before I store the data how much I will get, so I think I cannot just append the data with its indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only immutable elements can be used as dictionary keys

This mean you can't use a list (mutable data type) but you can use a tuple as the key of your dictionary: `dict_name[(i, j, k)] = data`

Comment: Great answer. And you can have a custom sort when you extract data or iterate over your dict. Look up additional parameters for `sorted()` function

Comment: Thanks that is exactly the  method I needed